# Replacing column values before calculation

Tags: sql, oracle11g

there I have table with 3 columns - let it be:
- number of order (tck.TICKETID),
- performer (perf.DISPLAYNAME),
- feedback for performer work after completing the order. 
I need to calculate average value to every performer to make rating. 
Not really hard:

```
SELECT 
perf.DISPLAYNAME AS "Performer",
 AVG (tck.mark)
FROM ticket tck
LEFT JOIN (
select 
  displayname, personid,  tck.TICKETID FROM PERSON  per
  left join ticket tck on tck.owner = per.personid
) perf on tck.TICKETID= perf.TICKETID
WHERE 
      tck.MARK IS NOT NULL AND
      perf.DISPLAYNAME IS NOT NULL
GROUP BY  perf.DISPLAYNAME 
ORDER BY  AVG (tck.mark) desc;
```

But there is one problem for me - maks are stored in database in reverse way, so 1=5; 2=4; 3=3; 2=1

I need to reverse it before calculating AVG value, tried with CASE in SELECT:

```
CASE AVG(TO_NUMBER(tck.MARK))
    WHEN 1 THEN 5
    WHEN 2 THEN 4 
    WHEN 3 THEN 3 
    WHEN 4 THEN 2 
    ELSE 99
  END AS Mark
```

but case works after calculation and I need before. Seems to me that case is wrong placed or my way to      solution the task isn't optimal.

As always will be very grateful for any piece of advice.

Comment: You are close just put the case in to the avg ? As you need to calculate avg after mark reversal.

Comment: Not really so. If I put case in SELECT it calculate values and than tries to replace them. So I get almost everywhere 99 instead of correct numbers. Or I don't understand your comment.

Comment: Correct, I'll accept it in 2 mins. Thanks a lot for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just put the case into the `avg` to get what you want. And you need make sure about your `ELSE` value because if the `NULL/0` both will be `99` in current query.

```
AVG(CASE 
WHEN TO_NUMBER(tck.MARK) = 1 THEN 5
WHEN TO_NUMBER(tck.MARK) = 2 THEN 4 
WHEN TO_NUMBER(tck.MARK) = 3 THEN 3 
WHEN TO_NUMBER(tck.MARK) = 4 THEN 2 
ELSE 99
END) AS Mark
```